# is it possible to use multi decorators on one method in nestjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I want to write less code, so I combine create and update code into one method, looks it can not work.

```
@Post('user')
@Put('user')
async createOrUpdateUser(@Res() res, @Req() req) {
  if (req.method == 'POST') {
    //do user creating work
  } else {
    //do user updating work
  }
}
```

I've tried it, but only the `@Post` decorator works here.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `@All` decorator to handle all request methods in one method:

```
@All('user')
async createOrUpdateUser(@Req() req) {
  switch (req.method) {
    case 'POST':
      return 'new user';
    case 'PUT':
      return 'updated user';
    default:
      return throw new NotFoundException();
  }
}
```

If you a define a `@Get('user')` handler *before* the `@All('user')` handler, it will handle the get requests. (I'd advice against doing that, see below.)

---

#### Advice

1) By injecting the framework specific response object with `@Res`, you'll lose most of the features that make nest so great such as interceptors  or serialization. Only do that, if you really need to.

2) I always prefer to extract common logic into a method or class instead of creating conditional branches within a method. In my opinion, this is a more readable and maintainable approach. It also makes other nest integrations easier for example using swagger to easily document your API.

```
@Put('user')
async update(@Body() body) {
  const user = await this.service.prepare(body);
  return this.service.updateUser(user);
}

@Post('user')
async update(@Body() body) {
  const user = await this.service.prepare(body);
  return this.service.createUser(user);
}
```

In this example, the common parts were extracted into `UserService#prepare`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be working like that, but you can do it as following so that you can avoid duplication.

```
@Post('user')
async createUser(@Res() res, @Req() req) {
  if(req.method=='POST')
  {
    //do user creating work
  }else {
    //do user updating work
  }
}

@Put('user')
async updateUser(@Res() res, @Req() req) {
 this.createUser(res, req);
}
```