# Does nestjs support Get and Post simultaneously on an action?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend, nestjs, web-frontend

I am new to nestjs and tring to apply `Get` and `Post` simultaneously on a method in my controller.
For simplicity, I just post the core logic code snippet:

**Customized Decorator**

```
import { Get, Post } from "@nestjs/common";
import { RenderReact } from 'my-personal-package';

export function Page(path: string, view?: React.ComponentType, methodDecorators?: ((path?: string | string[]) => MethodDecorator)[]): MethodDecorator {
  return (target: any, key: string, desc: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    const decorators = [
      Get(path), // Add Get first.
      Post(path) // Add Post then.
    ];

    if (view) {
      decorators.push(RenderReact(view)); // RenderReact will return a MethodDecorator as well.
    }
    decorators.forEach(decorate => decorate(target, key, desc));
    return desc;
  };
}
```

**Controller method**:

```
@Page("my-path", ThisIsMyPageFunctionalComponent, [Post]) // Post was from @nestjs/common
async return() {
  // method logic
}
```

The array "decorators" at the very beginning in the **Page** function,

1. Add **Get**, then **Post**, Only **Post** works.
2. Add **Post**, then **Get**, Only **Get** works.

How can we apply Get/Post simultaneously here?

Comment: I think you can't do that due to how the HTTP decorator factory works. [Here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/5974b6fed12dfe3d0846cb48dcf2cb449bde2557/packages/common/decorators/http/request-mapping.decorator.ts#L26-L27) you can see that only the last metadata is attached to the target method. Maybe there is a way to do that but not using `Get` and `Post`

Comment: btw see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55157583/

Answer (score 1):

As @Micael Levi mentioned above, as the machanism of how decorator factory works, we can not apply both Get and Post in this way. I have tried it for a long time.

Please refer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55157583/is-it-possible-to-use-multi-decorators-on-one-method-in-nestjs), like @Kim Kern posted

1. We extracted common logic into a method.
2. Separate the method Get and Post which will call the common logic.