# Handling both PUT and PATCH requests in the same method in NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I'm using NestJS to build a web application. I'm trying to handle both PUT and PATCH requests in the same method. Here's what I've tried:

```js
import { Controller, Put, Patch, HttpCode, Body } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('example')
export class ExampleController {
  @Put()
  @Patch()
  async updateResource(@Body() data: any) {
    // Handle both PUT and PATCH requests
    // Access the request body using the `data` parameter
    // ...
    return { message: 'Resource updated successfully' };
  }
}
```

However, only the PUT `/example` route seems to work, and the PATCH request does not get processed. I want to be able to handle both types of requests in the `updateResource` method. Are there any additional adjustments I need to make or alternative solutions to achieve this?

I appreciate any insights or guidance. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55157583/is-it-possible-to-use-multi-decorators-on-one-method-in-nestjs

Comment: I think this answer does not solve my problem. My issue lies in two similar methods, and using "@All" wouldn't be correct either.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could quickly call the same method from both routes, either in the controller or the associated service, such as:

```
import { Controller, Put, Patch, HttpCode, Body } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('example')
export class ExampleController {

  @Put()
  async putMethod(@Body() data: any) {
    return putAndPatchMethod(data);
  }

  @Patch()
  async patchMethod(@Body() data: any) {
    return putAndPatchMethod(data);
  }

  async putAndPatchMethod(data: any) {
    // Handle both PUT and PATCH requests
    // Access the request body using the `data` parameter
    // ...
    return { message: 'Resource updated successfully' };
  }

}
```

Its clear both routes do the same thing, and its easy changing that later.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I want a different solution.